# How can I create a new function for a python module when "clinic" is used?

Tags: python, c, module

For certain reasons I have to extend python's ssl module. In particular I need a second version of load_cert_chain() in C.

My problem is not related to openssl but rather how to cope with "clinic":
In front of the original function there is a clinic-input:

```
/*[clinic input]
_ssl._SSLContext.load_cert_chain
certfile: object
keyfile: object = NULL
password: object = NULL

[clinic start generated code]*/

static PyObject *
_ssl__SSLContext_load_cert_chain_impl(PySSLContext *self, PyObject *certfile,
                                  PyObject *keyfile, PyObject *password)
/*[clinic end generated code: output=9480bc1c380e2095 input=7cf9ac673cbee6fc]*/
{
    PyObject *certfile_bytes = NULL, *keyfile_bytes = NULL;
    pem_password_cb *orig_passwd_cb = self->ctx->default_passwd_callback;
    ...
```

So far I know, that the _ssl__SSLContext_load_cert_chain_impl is the implementation of load_cert_chain and called within _ssl__SSLContext_load_cert_chain, which is defined within the header file _ssl.c.h
This, however, is auto-generated by clinic- isn't it?

So where do I start to define my new function load_cert_chain2 as a copy of the original, since everything is auto-created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clear some misunderstanding:

No, the argument clinic has nothing to do with linking C functions to Python functions!

The argument clinic just creates a function signature for a C function. In your example

```
/*[clinic input]
_ssl._SSLContext.load_cert_chain
certfile: object
keyfile: object = NULL
password: object = NULL
```

The `_ssl__SSLContext_load_cert_chain_impl` C function will be exposed in the signature as `_ssl._SSLContext.load_cert_chain` with the three arguments expecting a python `object`: `certfile` as positional argument and `keyfile, password` as optional arguments with a default of `NULL`.

---

How or when the function is called isn't linked to the argument clinic. The method declaration is done in `Modules/clinic/_ssl.c.h`:

```
#define _SSL__SSLCONTEXT_LOAD_CERT_CHAIN_METHODDEF    \
    {"load_cert_chain", (PyCFunction)_ssl__SSLContext_load_cert_chain, METH_FASTCALL, _ssl__SSLContext_load_cert_chain__doc__}

static PyObject *
_ssl__SSLContext_load_cert_chain(PySSLContext *self, PyObject **args, Py_ssize_t nargs, PyObject *kwnames)
{
    [...]
    return_value = _ssl__SSLContext_load_cert_chain_impl(self, certfile, keyfile, password);
}
```

and it's explicitly added as method to the `_SSLContext` class in `Modules/_ssl.c`:

```
static struct PyMethodDef context_methods[] = {
    [...]
    _SSL__SSLCONTEXT_LOAD_CERT_CHAIN_METHODDEF
    [...]
    {NULL, NULL}        /* sentinel */
};

[...]

static PyTypeObject PySSLContext_Type = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL, 0)
    "_ssl._SSLContext",                        /*tp_name*/
    sizeof(PySSLContext),                      /*tp_basicsize*/
    [...]
    context_methods,                           /*tp_methods*/
    [...]
};
```

---

So the argument clinic isn't responsible for assigning the method to a class. That's done with a wrapper function `_ssl__SSLContext_load_cert_chain` around `_ssl__SSLContext_load_cert_chain_impl` and assigned to the class using a `PyMethodDef` struct that's assigned to the class.

Now you know that there is no auto-generated linking, I don't know if that helps when you want to replace that function. I don't know how you could easily do that (argument clinic or no clinic) without recompiling Python or copying all relevant files into your extension.

Comment: I know what you wrote. But in order to create a copy of load_cert_chain, load_cert_chain2, do I have to copy also the relevant part in the _ssl.c.h ? I think thats the wrong way, because the h file is auto generated.

Comment: in fact I have not even clinic.py installed. What I did is to modify _ssl.c.h with the new code according to the original. It works and the new method can be called from python interpreter.

Comment: could you clarify what you want to change?